# how to link css files in organization github pages

Tags: css, github, github-pages

I'm trying to add an external `css` file in my `index.html`.

Organization-name - `codehunks`

My directory structure is as:

```
codehunks.github.io
    _layouts/
        style.css
    LICENSE.txt
    README.rst
    index.html
```

I tried adding it as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_layouts/styles.css"/>
```

but it didn't work.
I searched and get to know that `raw.github.com/../..` doesn't work in case of `css/text`

I found some articles adding it by providing link as `[username].github.io/[repo]/[folder]/[filname]` but this didn't work for my organization.

I tried adding it as `codehunks.github.com/codehunks.github.io/_layouts/style.css` but the link is giving me `404 not found` response.

Any possible solution or I'm following something wrong.

Here's my page [codehunks.github.io](http://codehunks.github.io) and here's my code [Source Code](https://github.com/codehunks/codehunks.github.io)

Comment: That's strange, it should work. If you don't receive any response here, try contacting GitHub.

Comment: Ah,I Renamed the folder `_layouts` to simply `css` and it is working now. Seriously strange

Comment: Ugh, now I remember. This is because of the GitHub's [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). Directories prefixed with `_` are considered to be used by Jekyll.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your style will work at /styles.css if you put it in the root, _layout folder is used by jekyll/ruby.

create a css folder in the root of your repo and put the style in there.

/css/style.css instead.

Comment: @gustavohenke mentioned it earlier. But thanks for pointing it out too. Though the answer is correct, can i get the `jekyll` docs for this in order to get started with it in the near future?